# What is the format of Eloqua Contact Id?

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

Bulk api is returning ids as for ex: "CTPOP000000000007" ,does this mean eloqua format is: first 5 letters are characters and the rest represent a number?

Answer (score 1):

Eloqua contact is an unique field.
It is formed of:

- C stands for contact
- TPOP is the instance login prefix
- 000000000007 is the id , so this means that this is the 7th id registered in your eloqua system